# Keras: dictionaries as validation_data

Tags: python, tensorflow, dictionary, validation, keras

From Keras manual I learn that the variable `validation_data` could be:

- A tuple `(x_val, y_val)` of NumPy arrays or tensors.
- A tuple `(x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights)` of NumPy arrays.
- A tf.data.Dataset.
- A Python generator or keras.utils.Sequence returning `(inputs, targets)` or `(inputs, targets, sample_weights)`.

My question is: since I am using multiple named inputs, could I use a tuple `(x_val, y_val)` as `validation_data`, where `x_val` is a dictionary of NumPy arrays (with keys equal to the names of the model's input) and `y_val` is a simple NumPy array?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How is your original data stored like? I can sketch out a more complete solution. But the answer to your question is, yes. In facts, that's what we do in our company. Although you might want to have tensors instead of numpy arrays in there. It also depends on what happens in your training loop (e.g. how is your model consuming that data).

Comment: Tried passing a dictionary as my `validation_data` and ran into the same issue as [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706535/keras-validation-loss-and-accuracy-stuck-at-0)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using multiple named inputs, you cannot pass a tuple `(x_val, y_val)` for the `validation_data` parameter (at least, currently, Keras does not support that). As per the [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) and [Keras](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) documentations:

> **validation_data** will override **validation_split**. **validation_data** could be:
>
> - A tuple **(x_val, y_val)** of Numpy arrays or tensors.
> - A tuple **(x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights)** of NumPy arrays.
> - A **tf.data.Dataset**.
> - A Python generator or **keras.utils.Sequence** returning **(inputs, targets)** or **(inputs, targets, sample_weights)**. **validation_data** is not yet supported with **tf.distribute.experimental.ParameterServerStrategy**.

**Potential solution:**

One potential solution is to concatenate the training and validation datasets and pass it to the `fit` method as arguments for `x` and `y`, while specifying the validation part using the `validation_split`. Note that:

> The validation data is selected from the last samples in the x and y data provided, before shuffling.

**More details**

Let's say your dataset has two inputs, e.g. in1 and in2, and two outputs, e.g. out1 and out2.

**Optional reading**

You can first shuffle your training and validation datasets as needed:

```
concat_xy_train=np.concatenate((train_in1, train_in2, train_out1, train_out2), axis=1)
concat_xy_val=np.concatenate((val_in1, val_in2, val_out1, val_out2), axis=1)
np.random.shuffle(concat_xy_train)
np.random.shuffle(concat_xy_val)
```

You can, then, retrieve your features and lables:

```
shuf_train_in1 = concat_xy_train[:,:len_in1]
shuf_train_in2 = concat_xy_train[:,len_in1:len_in1+len_in2]
shuf_train_out1 = concat_xy_train[:,len_in1+len_in2:len_in1+len_in2+len_out1]
shuf_train_out2 = concat_xy_train[:,len_in1+len_in2+len_out1:]

shuf_val_in1 = concat_xy_val[:,:len_in1]
shuf_val_in2 = concat_xy_val[:,len_in1:len_in1+len_in2]
shuf_val_out1 = concat_xy_val[:,len_in1+len_in2:len_in1+len_in2+len_out1]
shuf_val_out2 = concat_xy_val[:,len_in1+len_in2+len_out1:]
```

**Concatenation of training and validation datasets**

```
train_val_in1 = np.concatenate((shuf_train_in1, shuf_val_in1), axis=0)
train_val_in2 = np.concatenate((shuf_train_in2, shuf_val_in2), axis=0)
train_val_out1 = np.concatenate((shuf_train_out1, shuf_val_out1), axis=0)
train_val_out2 = np.concatenate((shuf_train_out2, shuf_val_out2), axis=0)
```

**Fitting thee model**

When fitting the model:

```
model.fit(
    {"in1": train_val_in1, "in2": train_val_in2},
    {"out1": train_val_out1, "out2": train_val_out2},
    validation_split=len_val/(len_val+len_train),
...
```